How to save files in a specific folder with Laravel Media library?
I am currently working on a project, and I'm having trouble with Laravel's Media Library image-saving function. When I save a file, it gets saved in a folder named with a number.
I want to have the files saved in a specific folder when I use toMediaCollection('avatars') in my code. Here's the relevant code snippet:
// Avatar image
if(!is_null($request->hasFile('avatar')))
   $user->addMediaFromRequest('avatar')->toMediaCollection('avatars');

How can I modify this so that when I save a file, it gets saved in the 'avatars' folder instead of a numerically named folder? Any help would be appreciated.
